# Having problems converting conditional where clause in LINQ back over to SQL

Tags: sql, linq, conditional-statements, where-clause

I've got myself in a bit of a pickle!

I've done a snazzy LINQ statement that does the job in my web app, but now I'd like to use this in a stored procedure:

```
var r = (from p in getautocompleteweightsproducts.tblWeights
                     where p.MemberId == memberid &&
                              p.LocationId == locationid

                     select p);

            if (level != "0")
                r = r.Where(p => p.MaterialLevel == level);

            if (column == "UnitUserField1")
                r = r.Where(p => p.UnitUserField1 == acitem);

            if (column == "UnitUserField2")
                r = r.Where(p => p.UnitUserField2 == acitem);

return r.OrderBy(p => p.LevelNo).ToList();
```

However, I can't for the life of me get the conditional where clause to work!!

If someone can point me in the right direction, I'd be most grateful.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.weights
WHERE member_id = @memberid
    AND location_id = @locationid
    AND material_level = CASE WHEN @level = '0' THEN material_level
                              ELSE @level END
    AND @acitem = CASE @column WHEN 'UnitUserField1' THEN unit_user_field_1
                               WHEN 'UnitUserField2' THEN unit_user_field_2
                               ELSE @acitem END
ORDER BY level_no
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net/), I'm pretty sure last time I played with that you could enter "LINQ to SQL" code and see the resulting SQL that produced.  Failing that, place a SQL trace/profiler on your code running the LinqTOSQL and find the query being executed in the trace.

Answer (score 0):

LukeH's answer will give you the correct rows, but there is something lost when you try to replace a query-generating-machine with a single query.  There are parts of that query that are opaque to the optimizer.

If you need the original queries as-would-have-been-generated-by-linq, there are two options.

- Generate every possible query and control which one runs by IF ELSE.
- Use Dynamic sql to construct each query (although this trades away many of the benefits of using a stored procedure).

If you do decide to use dynamic sql, you should be aware of the [curse and blessings](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) of it.

Comment: Thanks for advice David - time constraints beckon so I'll cheat and use Luke's answer for now!!!